# Pegar select selecionado (só está pegando primeiro valor)

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

Um alert é exibido (com o plugin sweetalert) e nesse alert tem um `select`com nomes. Após selecionar o nome, a pessoa tem que clicar no botão **Adicionar**, quando a pessoa clica a `function` do código abaixo é executada e nela eu coloquei um código para capturar o `option` selecionado, só que o resultado é sempre o do primeiro `option`.

```
$("a#AddListaPresentes").click(function(){

                var conteudoListaPresente = $("#contentLP").html();
                var id_produto = $(this).attr('ref');
                var baseURL = $("#baseURL").val();

                swal({
                  title: "Adicionar a Lista de Presentes",
                  text: conteudoListaPresente,
                  html: true,
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  closeOnConfirm: false,
                  closeOnCancel: true,
                  cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                  confirmButtonText: 'Adicionar'
                },function(){

                    var selecionado = $("#ListaPresenteSelect option:selected");

                    alert(selecionado);

                    if($.trim(selecionado) !=  false){

                        $.ajax({

                            url: baseURL+'ajax/adicionaritemlistadepresentesx',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data:{id:selecionado, produto:id_produto},

                            success:function(callback){

                                if(callback){
                                    swal("Adicionado!", "Produto adicionado a sua lista de casamento (:", "success");
                                }else{
                                    swal("Opss", "Ocorreu um erro ao adicionar o produto: "+callback, "error");
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }

                });
            })
```

Answer (score 7):

Existem algumas formas de pegar o valor, como não tem seu HTML vou citar algumas:

Se seu formulário não possuir o atributo `value`, algo como:

```
<select id="ListaPresenteSelect">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

Você pode pegar direto, assim:

```
$('#ListaPresenteSelect').val();
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/3mhrb0Lt/)

Se você possuir um atributo `value` e quiser acessa-lo, basta usar o exemplo descrito acima.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/3mhrb0Lt/2/)

Se possuir um `value` e quiser pegar o texto selecionado pode fazer assim:

```
$('#ListaPresenteSelect option:selected').text();
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/3mhrb0Lt/1/)

No seu exemplo acima, parace estar faltando só pegar o texto com o método `.text()`.

Comment: o pior é que não funcionou. Quando clico no "Adicionar" ele da o alert só que o resultado só sai 1 (que é o value do primeiro item). Não sei se tem algo haver, mas esse "Adicionar" é um botão do plugin que só faz executar a `function` do código que postei.

Comment: melhor olhe esse [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/xe096w10/126/) hehe'

Comment: Não entendi o porque entã o.O.. Porque no meu está parecido com o código do `jsdiddle` ... A única diferença é que o <select> é renderizado em uma `<div>` com o `display:hidden` e quando a pessoa clica em um link o jQuery pega o `HTML` dessa `div` e joga no plugin para exibir o select com os options

Comment: só para esclarecer, o seu select fica dentro do modal gerado pelo sweetalert  ? :D

Comment: Sim, consegui resolver.. Era porque como eu pegava o conteudo renderizado da `<div>` que estava com `display:none` e depois só criava mais um igual e colocava dentro do modal, então ficava 2 select com o mesmo nome e dava pau... Consegui arrumar.. Obrigadoo!

Comment: @AlissonAcioli esqueceu de dar upvote e de fechar essa ;) ... (depois apago este comentário...)

Answer (score 0):

Esse vai selecionar o que for clicado

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // get estado

    //variaveis{
    var estado = $('select');

    //variaveis}  

    estado.change(function () {
        console.log(estado.val());
    });
    //final get estado
});
```