# Como saber qual option do select foi selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um `<select>` e preciso saber qual `<option>` foi selecionado.

```
<select class="formacao">
        <option>Ensino fundamental incompleto</option>
        <option>Ensino fundamental completo</option>
        <option>Ensino médio incompleto</option>
        <option>Ensino médio completo</option>
        <option>Ensino Superior</option>
</select>
```

Tentei resolver aqui mais o jQuery só me retorna o valor do primeiro option.

Preciso saber quando a opção "Ensino superior" for selecionado

Comment: Corrigindo ali "Mas o jQuery"

Comment: Possivel duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95778/pegar-select-selecionado-s%C3%B3-est%C3%A1-pegando-primeiro-valor

Answer (score 6):

Tipo algo assim:

```
var conceptName = $('#aioConceptName').find(":selected").text();
```

Você ainda poderia fazer direto em javascript:

```
var box = document.getElementById('aioConceptName');

conceptName = box.options[box.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Não sabe como me ajudou.

Comment: tranquilo @Alan marque a pergunta como resolvida

Answer (score 1):

Poderia incluir um valor pra cada option como por exemplo

```
    <select class="formacao">
            <option value="1">Ensino fundamental incompleto</option>
            <option value="2">Ensino fundamental completo</option>
    </select>
```

Pra receber o texto Você pode usar

```
    //caso estivesse no primeiro item
    $('.formacao option:selected').text() // para texto (Ensino fundamental incompleto)
    $('.formacao').val() // para valor (1)
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Answer (score 1):

Vou exemplificar com o jQuery como solicitado na pergunta.

#### HTML 5

```
<select class="formacao">
    <option value="1" >Ensino fundamental incompleto</option>
    <option value="2" >Ensino fundamental completo</option>
    <option value="3" >Ensino médio incompleto</option>
    <option value="4" >Ensino médio completo</option>
    <option value="5" >Ensino Superior</option>
</select>
```

Aqui eu defini em todas as *options* alguns *values* que vão facilitar bastante na hora de identificar.

#### jQuery

```
$('.formacao').change(function () {
  let n = $('.formacao').val();

  //Operador lógico
  if (n == 5) {
    console.log('A 5ª opção foi selecionada!');
  }
});
```

Utilizando o jQuery a função ficaria assim.

Answer (score 0):

Para fins de ajuda ao próximo, segue o exemplo completo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formacao').change(function () {

        var es = document.getElementById('formacao');

        esValor = es.options[es.selectedIndex].value;

        alert(esValor);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#formacao').change(function() {

    valor = $("#formacao").val();

    alert(valor);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="formacao" id="formacao">
  <option>Ensino fundamental incompleto</option>
  <option>Ensino fundamental completo</option>
  <option>Ensino médio incompleto</option>
  <option>Ensino médio completo</option>
  <option>Ensino Superior</option>
</select>
```

Comment: O código realiza a tarefa. Uma explicação de seu funcionamento agregaria valor a sua resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode pegar o option selecionado da mesma maneira que pega o valor de um input com JAVASCRIPT.

No Javascript você pega o select usando o DOM e joga em uma variável, e depois é só jogar o seletor.value dentro de uma variável, ela vai guardar o valor do seu seletor:

```
const seletor = document.getElementsByClassName('formacao')[0]
const valorSelecionado = seletor.value
```

E pronto.

Você pode testar colocando um botão no html pra quando ser clicado ele mostrar a variável valorSelecionado no console.

HTML: `<button onclick="checaValor()"></button>`

JavaScript:

```
const seletor = document.getElementsByClassName('formacao')[0]

function checaValor(){
    const valorSelecionado = seletor.value
    console.log(valorSelecionado)
}
```

Dicas:

1. Se você só estiver usando um seletor, use ID ao invés de class, class normalmente são usadas para referenciar vários elementos, quando queremos referenciar apenas um elemento usamos ID.
2. O valor padrão do select não é undefined! O valor padrão do select vai ser o valor do primeiro option.